# An understanding of a sphere symmetric metric

Tags: metric-spaces, spheres, general-relativity

When we use the polar coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^4$, which are
\begin{aligned}
&t\\
&x=r \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
&y=r \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
&z=r \cos \theta,
\end{aligned}

the sphere symmetric metric is
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{d} s^{2}=-A(r, t) d t^{2}+B(r, t) d t d r+C(r, t) d r^{2}+D(r, t)\left(d \theta^{2}+\sin ^{2} \theta d \varphi^{2}\right)
\end{aligned}

where $A,B,C,D$ is a function depending on $r,t$.

Here, the term $\sin ^{2} \theta \mathrm{d} \phi^{2}$ looks like depending on the angle $\theta$ and it looks like a contradiction to the sphere symmetry.

I think that the sphere symmetric metric does not depend on the angles $\theta,\phi$ but depends only on the radius $r$. Is it a mistake? Please, teach me the definition of sphere symmetry.

Comment: Just to confirm, $w$ is a conformal time coordinate and not a fourth spatial coordinate? Because the metric you have doesn't line up with the change of coordinates written down (a minor point $A$ would also always be $1$ for this coordinate system, there is no function)

Comment: You are right. I have rewrited it. Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: The variables $\theta$ and $\phi$ just parametrize the unit two-sphere (a sphere with Gaussian curvature $1$).  The metric components $g_{\theta\theta}$ and $g_{\phi\phi}$ do not depend on them, but as others, only on $r$ and $t$.